# How can I share data on facebook?

Tags: android, facebook

I am creating a news application and want to share the whole contents of the news which the user reads, and have a button named "facebook". As the user clicks on the button, the facebook login window should open on my activity, and after the user logs in, the whole story should post on his wall.

Comment: Why don't use the facebook like button? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use one of Facebook *["Social Channels"](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/)* (like "Like" or "Send" buttons or "Feed Dialog") to publish content and for logging users in you may use [`FB.login`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) or [`Facebook::getLoginUrl`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/)

You really should read some documentation on subject:

- [Facebook for Websites](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/)
- [Development of Apps on Facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/)
- [Social Channels](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/)
- [Social Plugins](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/)

Answer (score 0):

In a broad sense you can use a share intent, however you may want a little more control than this offers.

A good example; http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/sharing-content-in-android-using-action_send-intent